# Automatically add data if foreign key is missing

Tags: c#, mysql, automation, foreign-keys

I have two tables in MySQL, let's say:

**Product**

```
id (unique)
name
```

**Purchases**

```
id (unique)
fk_productid (references Product.id)
buyerName
```

I am using InnoDB and created a foreign key from `purchases.fk_productid` to `product.id`.

Assume we have no products in the table so far and no purchases. Now someone purchases the product with id 10 which will cause a failure if I simply try this query:

> INSERT INTO purchases (fk_productid, buyerName) VALUES (10, "Andreas")

---

What can I do to insert the purchase anyway? I can think of two things:

1. Add NULL as `fk_productid`, but how do I do that directly in the query if it fails?
2. Add a dumy entry in the `product` table, but how would I do that? How can I automatically add

   ```
   INSERT INTO products (id, name) VALUES (10, "???")
   ```

before the other query?

Should this be done with triggers, procedures or is there even an easier way I don't know?

Comment: Why don't you check that the product is valid first, then proceed with the insert.

Comment: Yeah but then I would need a SELECT for each entry. Do you think that this is the only way to go? I have probably hundreds of SELECTS like that when I update the table with my C# "cronjob".

Comment: Is There an option in inndodb to not check for referential integrity constraint?

Comment: Yeah a constraint on the table would work. Or you could create a Stored Proc which checks the Product validity first and before the insert. You could also cache product list to increase performance.

Comment: @Simon: Maybe, that is why I am asking here - I don't know. If there is no good solution I will do it as Marcel proposed. I hoped there is a better solution than selects (performance wise).

Comment: @andreas The utility of a foreign key is the integrity of the data. If you can't guarantee, I'd suggest to either not have a FK and just go with it, or to not check for integrity (I'm more in the MsSql world, I do not know if this is an option in MySql, I'm guessing it is)

Answer (score 1):

Well, first I would say you're probably safer to refuse the order and tell the user to come back, because you should be doing things like checking stock, price, etc. in your product table before verifying a purchase.

Anyway, this should solve your immediate problem:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO products (id, name, isDummy) VALUES (10, "TBD", 1); // does nothing if product id 10 already exists
INSERT INTO purchases (fk_productid, buyerName) VALUES (10, "Andreas");
```

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with this solution:

> INSERT INTO purchases (fk_productid, buyerName) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM product WHERE id=10 LIMIT 1), "Andreas");

I agree that in production this case should never happen - don't worry, it won't. This was more of a simple description of a larger problem I had. ;-)

Thanks for your ideas before!